# Can't find /Developer folder for ios in Dreamweaver?

Tags: ios, cordova, dreamweaver

I have installed xcode 4.3.2. on my macbook and want to use dreamweavers buildin phonegap tool. I am supposed to point from dreamweaver to my /Develop folder, but can't seem to find the folder??? I have tryid searching allmost everysthing using apples Finder but with no luck?

Am I overlooking something?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` as the xcode folder. I'm not sure whether it'll work though. Xcode 4.3 marked the original `/Developer` folder deprecated. The new location is contained in the .app folder.

Comment: You see... I don't have anything called .app or xcode in my applicationsfolder or even when I search? But xcode works just fine??? Does "hidden" folders exists on ios?

Comment: You don't have Xcode.app in your application folder? Where is it installed? If you installed it through the Mac App Store, this should be the default location. A Mac OS X .app file is actually a folder.